# ¿Cómo obtener valor de un select en html?

Tags: html

es que necesito saber como puedo obtener el valor de un select que no esta dentro de un form en html para después enviarlo por método post a php.

Aquí esta el código:

```
<select id="item">
         <option value="volvo">s300</option>
         <option value="saab">s500</option>
         <option value="mercedes">s700</option>
         <option value="audi">s750</option>
        </select>
                </div>
            </section>


      <section id="info">
        <h3>carro.</h3>
        <div class="contenedor">
          <div class="info-pet">


            <form  action="enviar.php" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="variable2" value="valor2" />
                <input type="submit" value="Seleccionar" id="boton" >
            </form>
```

Comment: Y porque simplemente no lo pones dentro del formulario?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo enviarás, por Ajax dese Javascript? Lo puedes recuperar así: `valorSelect=getElementById("item").value;`

Comment: esque estaba pensando si depronto se podia hacer todo por medio de html como lo hago con un formulario sin java, entonces no se puede?

Comment: **No, no se puede, por motivos de seguridad.** HTML funciona del lado del cliente, lo mismo que Javascript o cualquier librería que use Javascript (como jQuery). Si tú quieres enviar algo al servidor tendrás que usar un lenguaje que corra en el servidor (PHP u otro). Lo que se suele hacer en estos casos es usar Ajax como intermediario entre el cliente (HTML)  y el servidor (PHP). Ajax envía la petición a un archivo PHP y al mismo tiempo recibe la respuesta.

Comment: entiendo gracias

Comment: hola mira ya estoy enviando datos del formulario en ajax pero tambien requiero que envie en la misma peticion lo del select como lo aria? el select es aparte del form

Answer (score 7):

Puedes usar jQuery para capturar su valor por medio del método `.val()`:

```js
$("#item").change(function(){
  var valor = $(this).val();
  
  console.log(valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="item">
 <option value="volvo">s300</option>
 <option value="saab">s500</option>
 <option value="mercedes">s700</option>
 <option value="audi">s750</option>
</select>
```

En este ejemplo he utilizado el evento `.change()` pero puedes hacerlo también asignando evento `click` a algún botón, eso depende de en que momento necesitas que sea capturado el valor.

---

También puedes usar JavaScript nativo usando `.value`

```js
var select = document.querySelector("#item");

select.addEventListener('change', capturarValor);

function capturarValor(){
  var valor = select.value;
  
  console.log(valor);
}
```

```html
<select id="item">
  <option value="volvo">s300</option>
  <option value="saab">s500</option>
  <option value="mercedes">s700</option>
  <option value="audi">s750</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Obtengo con javascript y mándalo haciendo la petición con ajax

```
//estos son ejemplos de datos
var valor = $('#item').val(),
    nombre = $('#input_nombre').val(), 
    edad = $('#input_edad').val()
// y así todos los datos que desees capturar y luego se los pasas a la 
//petición ajax

$.ajax({
  url:'ruta de la petición',
  type:'POST',
  data:{valor_selecet:valor,nom:nombre,ed:edad},
  success:function(datos){
      //si la petición devuelve datos 
      //los capturas con la variable datos
    }
})
```

si es al pulsar un botón, el código quedaría dentro del evento click del botón,

```
$('#id_salvar').click(function(){
      //aquí pondrías el código anterior
})
```

**PD:** Importa jquery

Comment: hola entiendo pero necesito enviar los datos de un form y de un select que esta aparte del form en la misma peticion es posible?

Comment: revisa la respuesta , la actualice

Comment: Disculpa valor_selecet: nom: ,ed:  que vienen siendo, las variables que resibe el php?

Comment: si en el servidor , donde revives la petición , tu obtendrías por ejemplo , una variable llamada datos, y en el server dirías  `datos.valor_select` para obtener el valor del select  o  `datos.ed` para el valor de la edad